# WS-Security using the ASMX file in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, soap, wsdl, asmx, ws-security

Basically I need to setup my ASMX file so that when I pull it up in a browser to display the WebMethod specification the Soap Header conforms to this format:

```
<soap:Header>
   <wsse:Security>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='SecurityToken-securityToken'>
         <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
         <wsse:Password>Password</wsse:Password>
         <wsu:Created>Timestamp</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

Back-story: I'm integrating with a client application that is already built (and owned by another company). Basically this client application already has their soap messages all set up from its past integrations with other companies. So we've opted to just build a web service using an ASMX file that matches the WSDL that they're already setup to consume.

Is it possible to get WS-Security working on an ASMX file or is ASMX too simplistic and I have to upgrade to WFC (which I really don't want to do)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a SOAP / WS-Security service using classic web services.  Here's [a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188947.aspx) from MSDN.

All of this is easier in WCF though.

EDIT:

Pulled the wrong link.  [Here's the one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wssecurity_usernametokens.aspx) I meant to paste (CodeProject tutorial that uses WSE 2, though WSE 3 is the latest release and I have used that exclusively pre-WCF).

Comment: @Eric: I looked at that link, and it's hardly a tutorial. It's just an article from 2002.

Comment: @John: You're right and you're wrong.  I did pull the wrong link from my bookmarks (updated post).  You're wrong in stating that legacy ASMX can't support WS-Security (see updated link).

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to get WS-Security working on an ASMX file or is ASMX too simplistic and I have to upgrade to WFC (which I really don't want to do)?

Yes, it is possible using [Web Services Enhancements 3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en) (an add-on for Visual Studio 2005 and ASMX).  See this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480575.aspx) for a WSE-3-specific tutorial and use the `usernameOverTransportSecurity` assertion, noting that this is **not** actually secure unless the connection takes place over a protected transport (i.e. SSL).

It is, however, **not recommended** that you do this, and I cannot fathom why you would not "want" to "upgrade to WCF" given the choice.  Please note the following very important **limitations of ASMX/WSE:**

- WSE is no longer a *supported* product.  Although it still *works*, it no longer receives updates **or even bug fixes**.
- No version of WSE will successfully integrate into Visual Studio 2008, or even Visual Studio 2005 running on Windows Vista x64 or newer.
- WCF goes to a lot of trouble to provide thread-safe client operations and allow proxies to exist for long periods of time (which in turn provide significant per-operation performance benefits).  WSE proxies, on the other hand, are disposable non-threadsafe objects that incur a setup time with every remote method invocation (even when using Secure Conversation).  This also makes them largely unsuitable for Dependency Injection and many other widely-used patterns.

These are just some of the reasons why you **shouldn't** use WSE anymore.  The reasons why you **should** use *WCF* on the client side are manifold, including but not limited to separation of the model and proxies, consumption of REST-based services, and better handling of collection types.

Unless you really *must* continue to use ASMX, please reconsider your refusal to move to WCF - unless the service does a lot of unusual things with XML serialization, it takes no more than 5 minutes to make the switch.

Comment: @Aoronaught: Thanks for all the info. The reason I'm hoping to stay away from a WCF service was because I heard it was easy to setup but a pain to deploy on the server. Are you aware of whether or not there are additional setup procedures needed for WCF aside from the simple "publish" command that Visual Studio 2008 provides? We've already deployed several ASMX services and deploying was as simple as clicking "publish". If WCF is just as simple then I'd happily make the switch.

Comment: @Adam: It should be just as simple. We don't use the VS "publish" command but our deployment is usually just a straight file copy.  Perhaps somebody said it was a pain to deploy because the .NET 3.5 Framework takes a long time to install if the server doesn't already have it?

Comment: You also need to learn "WCML", or better known as "WCF Configuration Markup Language". You spend your hours staring blankly at configuration files with its ga-zillions options. 

For the first few days nothing works, then by magic, one tweaked setting makes the damn thing work. you put bold warnings in the config file comments to warn others to NEVER EVER touch the file again on pain of death. 

Otherwise WCF is a breeze. Go for it. :-)

Comment: I appreciate this  is a late comment, but having just attempted to get a WSE-style WS-security ASMX service working in WCF, unless I am missing a trick - it is the most convoluted and err difficult thing ever. So much so I have given up, as there are no useful errors to help me get it working. All help obviously welcomed though, as I would much rather use it. My biggest problem is not finding any decent documentation on the web on how to use it!

Comment: @harrison: There's lots of help on the web; try starting [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2007/07/18/interoperability-between-wcf-and-wse-3-0.aspx).  If that doesn't work for you, you should start a question explaining what you've tried and what's not working (what error you get, etc.)

Comment: @aaronaught - I have, but not many people have answered. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945140/implementing-ws-security-within-wcf-proxy

Comment: @harrison: That question refers to Axis.  Is it Axis or WSE?  They may be similar, but they are not the same.  The WSDL in that question appears to be using the WS-Security spec from 2002, which is very old and I think corresponds to WSE 2.0; WSE 3.0 and WCF are not wire-level compatible with that at all.

Answer (score 2):

No, legacy ASMX web services do not support WS-Security, or any of the other WS-* standards.

Since Microsoft now considers ASMX web services to be "legacy technology", you should be doing this work using WCF.

---

Another answer suggests using WSE. This is even less of a solution. WSE is flat-out obsolete, and should only be used as a last resort.